# Model of a rigid body in $SE(3)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-geometry, rotations, rigid-transformation

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup
\newcommand{\bbeta}{\boldsymbol{\beta}}
\newcommand{\bomega}{\boldsymbol{\omega}}
\newcommand{\bnu}{\boldsymbol{\nu}}
\newcommand{\p}{\boldsymbol{p}}
\newcommand{\R}{\boldsymbol{R}}
\newcommand{\x}{\boldsymbol{x}}
\newcommand{\f}{\boldsymbol{f}}
\newcommand{\v}{\boldsymbol{v}}
\newcommand{\w}{\boldsymbol{w}}
\newcommand{\y}{\boldsymbol{y}}
\newcommand{\s}{\boldsymbol{s}}
\newcommand{\g}{\boldsymbol{g}}
\renewcommand{\u}{\boldsymbol{u}}
%% OLD MACROS (by IROS 2016 Paper)
\newcommand{\calS}{\mathcal{S}}
\newcommand{\calW}{\mathcal{W}}
\newcommand{\calA}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\calB}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{\bcalB}{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}}
% \newcommand{\graph}{\mathcal{G}}
\newcommand{\calV}{\mathcal{V}}
\newcommand{\calE}{\mathcal{E}}
\newcommand{\calG}{\mathcal{G}}
\newcommand{\calK}{\mathcal{K}}
\newcommand{\calN}{\mathcal{N}}
\newcommand{\calO}{\mathcal{O}}
$

I have a rigid body $i$ in 3D space ($SE(3)=\mathbb{R}^3\times SO(3)$). To this rigid body is associated a body frame $\calB$. In addition to that we can define a world-frame with the letter $\calW$.

$\p_i$ is the position of the center of gravity of the rigid body expressed in the *world* frame
$\R_i$ is the rotation matrix which allows to go from $\calB$ to $\calW$. Therefore if I apply a velocity $\v_i$ in $\calB$ the new position of our body in $\calW$ will be:

$\p_i+\R_i\v_i\Delta t$

where $\Delta t$ is the amount of time for which I applied the velocity $\v_i$

If, I want to apply also an angular velocity $\w_i$ (expressed in $\calB$) to the rigid body $i$ the new rotation matrix associated to the object $i$ will be

$\exp_{\R_i}(\w_i \Delta t)$

Does this make sense for you?

$\endgroup$

Comment: Sorry, but because it is easier for me to copy the equations from the report I have. 

If it is not correct, or against the policy of the website I can change it sorry.

Comment: You can read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26519/when-is-it-ok-to-use-newcommand-and-declaremathoperator?cb=1.

Comment: Thanks. I followed this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26533/207327

I hope now it is ok.

Comment: You could just redefine `\mathcal` as `\cal` that takes one parameter so you don't have to redefine it for every letter you need.